# Pandas - Aggregating and Plotting Results

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, aggregation

I have what I think should be a fairly simple question, but I have been fighting with it for hours

I want to do an aggregation on a pandas dataframe and then plot it using matplotlib

I start with a huge table of years and models of cars.   I then want to calculate the aggregate sales price and a percentage of asking prices.

I do that as follows

```
percent_asking_price =(df.groupby(['year','model'])['salesprice'].sum()/df.groupby(['year','model'])['askingprice'].sum())*100
```

That seems to do what I want it to do, but then I don't know what to do with the output - it returns output that looks like:

[image: Sample Output Data]

From that point on, I can't figure out what to do with it.. I want to graph the combination of year and model name using matplotlib to make it look something like this:

[image: Sample Chart]

A bit frustrated because this is something I can do really quickly using ddply and ggplot in r, but just can't get anywhere here

I have tried converting the output to a dataframe, but that didnt get me anywhere

Would really appreciate help

A small set that will show the results follows:

```
year,model,salesprice,askingprice
2009,Taurus,25410,30000
2009,Taurus,8698,10000
2009,Maxima,11135,15000
2009,Maxima,8500,10000
2010,Corvette,25000,30000
2010,Corvette,18320,20000
2010,Trans Am,32000,35000
2010,Trans Am,23620,25000
```

Finally  -is there a way to convert the output to a dataframe that looks as follows, so I can do further work on the output?  I don't want to lose the values in the first column..

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your original data before grouping so we can reproduce your whole question.

Comment: year,model,salesprice,askingprice
2009,Taurus,25410,30000
2009,Taurus,8698,10000
2009,Maxima,11135,15000
2009,Maxima,8500,10000
2010,Corvette,25000,30000
2010,Corvette,18320,20000
2010,Trans Am,32000,35000
2010,Trans Am,23620,25000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [383]: df_plt = ((df.groupby(['year','model'])['salesprice'].sum() \
   .....:            / \
   .....:            df.groupby(['year','model'])['askingprice'].sum())*100).reset_index()

In [384]: df_plt
Out[384]:
   year     model      0
0  2009    Maxima  78.54
1  2009    Taurus  85.27
2  2010  Corvette  86.64
3  2010  Trans Am  92.70

In [385]: df_plt['Year_Model'] = df_plt.year.astype(str) + ' ' + df_plt.model

In [386]: df_plt
Out[386]:
   year     model      0     Year_Model
0  2009    Maxima  78.54    2009 Maxima
1  2009    Taurus  85.27    2009 Taurus
2  2010  Corvette  86.64  2010 Corvette
3  2010  Trans Am  92.70  2010 Trans Am


In [387]: df_plt = df_plt.set_index('Year_Model')[[0]].rename(columns={0:'Percent Asking Price'})

In [388]: df_plt
Out[388]:
               Percent Asking Price
Year_Model
2009 Maxima                   78.54
2009 Taurus                   85.27
2010 Corvette                 86.64
2010 Trans Am                 92.70

In [389]: matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

In [390]: ax = df_plt.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)

In [391]: ax.yaxis.grid(True)
```

[image]

Comment: That works, but how did you get the Pct to show up in the legend?  Also, is there a way to just display the values as concatenated text (i.e. 2009 Taurus) rather than the (2009, Taurus)?   Thanks

Comment: You are amazing.. Thank you!  So disappointed R is so much easier.. this is crazy